# Adding value in input text field using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a small problem.I want to add value inside the input text field which is fetching from DB.

Suppose i have a input field like below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Receipt No">
```

I have to add `@user.Receipt_No` inside it as its value.This value is fetching from user table of DB.Please help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Receipt No" value="<%= @user.Receipt_No %>">
```